# Pygame window does not open via python launcher

Tags: python, macos, pygame

'''code'''
    #!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *

```
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
```

Comment: using a mac osx system

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

You had to import pygame, change `if event.type == QUIT:` `if event.type == pygame.QUIT:`, and update the screen with `pygame.display.update()`